# Let $K$ $=$ $\left<[7]\right>$. Find all the left cosets of $K$ in $U(30)$

Tags: group-theory

$U(30) = \{[1], [7], [11], [13], [17], [19], [23], [29]\}$

$K$ $=$ $\left<[7]\right>$ $=$ $\{[1], [7], [13], [19]\}$

So for computing the left cosets do I need to do these calculations? Using the definition for any $g ∈ U(30)$, $gH=\{gh|h∈U(30)\}$.

$[1]K, [7]K, [11]K, [13]K, [17]K, ..., [29]K$.

Given the size of K, this will be a rather tedious task for me, so I would like to know if I am correct before trying myself.

Thank you!

Comment: As $|U(30)|=8$ and $|K|=4$, then there are only two cosets, one of which is $K$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So will I go through my calculations and discover a lot of the left cosets are equal to each other?

Comment: If two (left) cosets have one element in common, then they are identical. So find one coset, then pick an element not in that coset, find its coset, and you're done. Try it!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Ah! I knew there was a "shortcut", but it was on the tip of my tongue. Much appreciated.

Comment: Let me encourage you, Charles, to write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson done and posted!

Answer (score 1):

**My solution:**

$[1]K = \{[1], [7], [13], [19]\} = K$

$[11]K = \{[11], [17], [23], [29]\}$